# Boto3 - How to keep session alive

Tags: python, session, amazon-s3, boto3, was

I have a process that is supposed to run forever and needs to updates data on a S3 bucket on AWS. I am initializing the session using boto3:

```
        session = boto3.session.Session()
        my_s3 = session.resource(
            "s3",
            region_name=my_region_name,
            aws_access_key_id=my_aws_access_key_id,
            aws_secret_access_key=my_aws_secret_access_key,
            aws_session_token=my_aws_session_token,
        )
```

Since the process is supposed to run for days, I am wondering how I can make sure that the session is kept alive and working. Do I need to re-initialize the session sometimes?

Note: not sure if it is useful, but I have actually multiple threads each using its own session.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no concept of a 'session'. The `Session()` is simply an in-memory object that contains information about how to connect to AWS.

It does not actually involve any calls to AWS until an action is performed (eg `ListBuckets`). Actions are RESTful, and return results immediately. They do not keep open a connection.

A `Session` is not normally required. If you have stored your AWS credentials in a config file using the AWS CLI `aws configure` command, you can simply use:

```py
import boto3

s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
```

The `Session`, however, is useful if you are using temporary credentials returned by an `AssumeRole()` command, rather than permanent credentials. In such a case, please note that credentials returned by AWS Security Token Service (STS) such as `AssumeRole()` have time limitations. This, however, is unrelated to the concept of a boto3 `Session`.

Answer (score 1):

As of [botocore#2766](https://github.com/boto/botocore/pull/2766), you can use the `tcp_keepalive` parameter ([docs](https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/config.html)):

```py
import botocore, boto3, environs

env = environs.Env()

S3_CLIENT = boto3.session.Session().client(  # this init style makes the client thread-safe
    "s3",
    config=botocore.client.Config(
        tcp_keepalive=env.bool("AWS_TCP_KEEPALIVE", True),
        max_pool_connections=env.int("AWS_S3_CONNECTIONS", 100),
        retries={
            "max_attempts": env.int("AWS_MAX_ATTEMPTS", 6),
            "mode": env("AWS_RETRY_MODE", "adaptive"),
        },
    ),
)
```